# post content from json by Django

Tags: django

wanna build an easy RESTful demo as below:
select song(show song id/song in html option) to show song information from json

models.py

```
class Music(models.Model):
    song = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    singer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

music_pick.html

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<select id="music_select">
  <option  value="" selected="selected">---Song Select---</option>
  {% for m in musics %}
   <option value="option{{ m.id }}" selected="selected">
       {{ m.song }}
   </option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
<p>The song, {{ song }} was sang by {{ singer }}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

and I have done the json produce part as url 'music/<^int:pk^>'
it would return:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "song": "ICE AND FIRE",
    "singer": "George  Martin",
}
```

how do I construct views.py or others in django 2.?

Comment: If you using template rendering no need to pass data to it in JSON format.
please add more info what content you have wrote in the view file

Comment: If you are going to do RESTful then use `django-restframework`.